# Unable to use Firebase Auth in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing an issue in my Flutter app using Firebase auth for Phone authentication, whenever i request OTP it provides me the following error:

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WAzK.png)

> W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 4834): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
>
> E/FirebaseAuth( 4834): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid app info in play_integrity_token
>
> D/FirebaseAuth( 4834): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +91**********, error - This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token ]

[FLUTTER DOCTOR SUMMERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ0Pa.png)

Also, I have updated the proper SH1 & SH256 Key and package name in Firebase

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output, your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the SHA of the machine you are using for signing/building the app. In Firebase Console go to your Firebase project configuration:

> Project Overview > Project settings > General

Then scroll down and configure your Android app with the debug and/or upload SHA. See how to configure phone authentication [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth). You should do it at least for Android.

Comment: I have already done this step and rechecked my keys, they are updated to firebase, but still the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

I recently put an answer here that may help you. I covered several steps and I can see that the ones that you reported were also faced by me

[SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null Firebase Phone Auth Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037392/sms-verification-code-request-failed-unknown-status-code-17093-null-firebase-p/78077647#78077647)

Answer (score 0):

**I think your project package has not matched! if another error you can visit my own answer!**

see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080803/19492096