# Firebase Authentication Google Sign in fails with message (code:10 message:10) Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services, google-signin

I am using flutter and have an issue using google sign in
I am using the same package name com.exemple for the 3 firebase projects and i am using the same signing certifcate and each project has the google sign in auth enabled.

we are uploading the app to google play and we use the internal testing in google play console  to test firebase project dev (exemple-development) and closed testing for testing firebase testing project  (exemple-testing) and prod for firebase prod project (exemple-production).
so all three firebase projects uses the same cert and app signing fingerprint and package name.
that creates an issue when using the google sign in method as it uses the same fingerprint cert and there is a conflict.

FYI : i added the debug, release and app signing SHA 1 fingerprint in all three firebase projects. And i added the client ID in the safelist of each project.

How can i fix the issue?
How can I use three different environments that uses the same package name com.exemple and implements the google sign in method.
Can i sign  the app using different certificate and upload them to the same google console project using the same package name?

i added the debug, release and app signing SHA 1 fingerprint in all three firebase projects. And i added the client ID in the safelist of each project.

Comment: So what is your main error. please explain in details.

Comment: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, m7.b: 10: , null, null)  that error appeared when i added two firebase project testing and dev and linked them using the same finger print and using same package name

Comment: [You can see this Answer, i'ope your problem will be solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080803/19492096)

Comment: thanks but this is not my issue. i am havig just confict of SHA1 and package name cuz the SHA1 exist in 3 firebase projects and link to the same package name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge Each Firebase project requires a unique SHA fingerprint for Google Sign-in to work correctly. You cannot use the same fingerprint for both testing and development projects.

You can generate separate SHA fingerprints for your testing and development environments.

Comment: thanks for responding,
you mean each time i create a bundle i use different upload-keystore.jks one for dev , one for testing env and one for prod for the same package name com.exemple.
doesn't that effect anything in google play store console. as you will see different Upload key certificate

Comment: While using different signing certificates for Firebase projects would resolve the conflict with Google Sign-In, it's important to note that this approach applies to the Firebase configuration and not the upload key used for Google Play Store releases.

For Google Play Store releases, the same upload key certificate must be used across all tracks for a particular app with the same package name. Therefore, the Unique App Signing Key approach would not directly address the issue of conflicts with Google Sign-In for apps uploaded to the Google Play Store.